# Auto hide Attribute Table Widget in ArcGIS Viewers for Flex?

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer

I'm trying to make a web application by using ArcGIS Viewers for Flex. I want that my Attribute Table can auto show up and hide by a button like happens on this [site](http://gis.calhouncounty.org/FlexViewer3.7/index.html?config=config-eSearch.xml&esearch=2&slayer=3&exprnum=1) but I don't know how to do it.

Any suggestions?

[image]